# Ignition Edifice examples fails to work properly

Tags: gazebo-edifice

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello!

I've been exploring Ignition Gazebo throw the examples and noticed that there are problems with examples with collada models. Either collada model visual is missing (like in camera_sensor.sdf for example) or model crashes (actor.sdf).

[Screenshot](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/16227240538594483.png)

[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/172gC11z52diPqp2ouwjdTPtUY4G4WEKX/view?usp=sharing)

I'm experiencing the same problem on 2 PCs (nvidia quadro / nvidia gtx).
OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Ignition Edifice binary installation

Does anyone have such problem? Any solutions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27038/ignition-edifice-examples-fails-to-work-properly/) by [temero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/48202/temero/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2021-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This is a [known issue with locales](https://github.com/ignitionrobotics/ign-rendering/issues/101).

The quick workaround until that's fixed is to set this environment variable:

```
export LC_NUMERIC="C"
```

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2021-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [temero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/48202/temero/) on 2021-06-16**:
Thx. Maybe put a note in the installation tutorial?